# DuplicateKeyException being thrown only on Linux WebLogic

Tags: java, linux, oracle, web-applications, weblogic

I have a relatively simple web application deployed on WebLogic that is using an Oracle database. When I finished developing the app and was ready to deploy it to the actual Linux server that the production WebLogic instance lives on, the app would throw a DuplicateKeyException on all inserts. If I run the app on my local windows machine and point the remote database, the app works just fine. I should also note that all reads from the database work perfectly with no issue in both environments.

I have since removed any primary key constraints on the table just to narrow down the issue, but every time I execute the insert query on the Linux deployment, it fails. Locally using the same code, same remote database, same version of WL (10.3.6) it works perfectly. So the big variable here is that same WAR file throws a DuplicateKeyException on the Linux 10.3.6 WL server, but it doesn't on the Windows. And the Linux instance is actually on an Oracle hosted environment, so while the DB and WL are on different servers, I would think that since my read commands work, the hosted environment shouldn't have anything to do with my inserts failing.

Any suggestions or help on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm not a Linux guy, just a Java developer and am at my wits end on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I tracked this problem down. Some of my inherited GWT code was catching the exception and throwing the DuplicateKeyException up to the client. I'm not sure why this exception was being thrown, but I had an idea to stop inheriting from a class that does some of the DB stuff for me that had a bunch of logging in it. Since the logging would be interacting with a Linux file system rather than Windows I figure it might be the difference. Voila as soon as I just did all the DB interactions in a more raw fashion and stopped using the extraneous code, it all worked. I didn't really dive into this any deeper other than to know that something with the logging was broken when deployed on Linux. This particular program is just going to be used by me to help me generate some CSVs for some business folks and typically I won't be deploying to this server anyhow, so I kind of stopped once I found the culprit.